# What is a good way to store an authenticated login?

Tags: javascript, html, openid, steam

If your website allows an off-site login (signing in through Google, Steam, etc.), what is the best way to store the callback result (such as Steam ID) so you "remember" they are logged in. And also, what is the safest way to do this so no one can "fake" being signed in?

For example, I have a user log into my website through Steam. I get their Steam ID (a big number), then store that in their cookie/session as their "login" until it expires.

Is there a better way to do this, and a safer way?

Comment: Cookies are more secure than local storage provided you use the right configuration (httponly, secure, samesite, expiration, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Usually these types of authentication use OAuth2, once the user has logged in what you get a couple tokens, one is the access_token that you use to communicate with the authentication provider's API and the other is a refresh token that you can use to get a new token when the access token is about to expire.

The access token contains some user info and the expiration of the token.
You can pate those tokens here to see their data: https://jwt.io/
on this website you can also find several libraries that you can use to problematically read those tokens.

You can keep the token in memory to avoid leaking it by storing it in either local storage or a cookie. For how to refresh or keep session take a look here: https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql

For more info on this workflows I'd recommend you chose the first type of authentication you want to integrate in you app and take a look at their OAuth documentation.

Here is googles documentation for JS OAuth, which is the one I think you are looking for:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#clientside

I'd also recommend you watch a quick YouTube video on how OAuth2 works to cover the basics before you jump into coding.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you put the token in Local Storage, you open yourself up to CSRF attacks: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Comment: You are right @DanielBank amending response, Thanks!

Comment: Right now they sign in through Steam (redirect and then back), and I receive their Steam ID, then add the Steam ID to the cookie under "steamID". I am already going to be switching to OAuth2 after learning about it. How would I stop people from "faking" logins and whatnot, so that their Steam login is authentic?